# I can't remove items from FlatList one by one by clicking via redux in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I've created a simple shopping app which has three screens including: `Home`, `Book Store` and `Cart` screens

I am using redux for updating all states, Everything works smoothly except one thing. I want the users when click on items in `Cart` they get removed one by one but the problem is that when i click on one item all of them get removed simultaneously

How can i fix this?

**Reducer code:**

```
import {
    ADD,
    REMOVE


} from '../actions/types';



const initialState = {

    items: [],
    counter: 0
}



export const cardReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD:
            return {
                ...state, items: state.items.concat({

                    name: action.payload.name,
                    index: Math.random(),
                    price: action.payload.price,
                    id: action.payload.id



                }), counter: state.counter + 1 }
            break;
        case REMOVE:
            return {
                ...state,
                items: state.items.filter((item) => {

                    item.index !== action.payload

                }), counter: state.counter - 1 }

            break;

        default:
            return state;
    }}
```

**Action code:**

```
import {
    ADD,
    REMOVE


} from './types';


export const addSomething = (item) => {

    return {

        type: ADD,
        payload: item

    }}


export const removeSomething = (index) => {

    return  {


            type: REMOVE,
            payload: index
        } }
```

**And this is the `Cart` screen codes:**

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { addSomething, removeSomething } from '../actions';




const Cards = (props) => {


  const { navigation } = props;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const items = useSelector(state => state.cardR.items)



  return (


      <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ width: '80%' }}>
          <FlatList
            data={items}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (

              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.button}
                activeOpacity={0.7}
                onPress={(index) => dispatch(removeSomething(item.index))}

              >

                <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>{item.name}</Text>
                <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>{item.price}</Text>

              </TouchableOpacity>

            )} />
        </View>
      </View>


  )}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems in the `index` property, likewise @giotskhada has mentioned in his response. The possible solution could be to check the removable item with its `id` instead of the index, which is already there to uniquely identify the each item.

Try this instead -

**Reducer Code:**

```
case REMOVE:
    return {
        ...state,
        items: state.items.filter((item) => {
            return item.id !== action.payload   // Id instead of index and return statement
        }), 
        counter: state.counter - 1 
    }

    break;
```

**Cart Screen Code:**

```
<TouchableOpacity
    style={styles.button}
    activeOpacity={0.7}
    onPress={(index) => dispatch(removeSomething(item.id))}>  // id instead of index

        <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>{item.name}</Text>
        <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>{item.price}</Text>

</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, I did as you said but issue is still persisting and also i removed ```index: Math.random()``` completely and wrote ```id: action.payload.id``` into case ```ADD``` in reducer but error is still there

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(item.id, action.payload)` in the filter method in your reducer and then we may confirm whether there is any problem or not?

Comment: I did, There is a problem, ```console.log(item.id)``` returns 1,2,3 which is correct but ```console.log(action.payload)```return 3,3,3 , I don't understand why ```action.payload``` is returning same number?

Comment: @roz333 I think its right, you are deleting the 3rd id's element and the action payload only contains the id = 3, its repeating because you are logging it int the filter which is nothing but a iterator / loop. I figure out what's the problem, the `return` need to be placed with `item.id !== action.payload`. Updated my answer.

Comment: You're really genius buddy, It worked, You're rock, Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem here is that `index` property is the same for all items.

Having randomly generated indices is a bad idea on its own, because you might end up with duplicate indices. Moreover, `Math.random()` is a pseudo-random floating-point number generator and shouldn't be trusted.

If you want to have a different index for each item, you have to do that another way. For example, you can have a `idCounter` state, which only increases by one when a new item is added. Then you can set new item's index to `state.idCounter` and be sure that it will be different from all the others.